# What exactly is the concept of returning to the one?

Tags: songwriting, styles

In riff writing, Tom Morello mentions his style with Tim Commerford was returning to the one. Is this basically just using the tonic chord as a drone? What exactly is meant by that? I believe I can give two examples of the type of riff writing.

> Heavy riffs: As the lead guitarist for Rage Against the Machine, Tom
> tends to favor the kind of heavy, mid-tempo rock that sounds best in
> the keys of E and F#. Those guitar riffs more often return to the
> “one,” meaning they always return to the root note at the beginning of
> each bar of music, giving them a repetitive, funky rhythm.
> Alternatively, some of Tom’s Audioslave riffs are chord progressions
> with a harmonic, melodic feel.

[SOURCE](https://www.masterclass.com/articles/who-is-tom-morello-explained#a-brief-introduction-to-tom-morello)

So is this typically what riff writing comprises of a drone on the tonic that goes somewhere and returns at the beginning of the next bar?

Comment: Can you post the quotation you're asking about in the question? Some more context would be helpful.

Comment: OK I have found some more info on the Masterclass website

Comment: 'One' could be both the tonic and the 1st beat of the bar. In fact both are used in the vast majority of songs - it establishes the tonality on the most important part of the bar.

Comment: *Returning* to the one only happens when you have *left* the one, which by definition is not a drone. A drone is staying on the same note(s) the whole time.

Answer (score 4):

Aside from the word “drone”, yes this is what Morello is talking about. There’s a tonic note for each of his riffs, most commonly D, E, or F#, and usually the first note of his riffs is that tonic.

By the way, that is **not** a drone. A drone is a note that is held for a while or indefinitely. Only one of his riffs would I say involves a drone, which is the verse “bagpipe” riff from “Voice of the Voiceless” where he actually plays the riff with the pitch knob on a Digitech Whammy Pedal.

“Killing In The Name” is an easy example of his riff writing. For both the verse and chorus riffs, the first note is D, which is the tonic of the song. Same with the verse riffs to “Freedom” and “Know Your Enemy” - there are many examples.

There are also some exceptions, such as the intro/interlude riff for “Know Your Enemy” which starts on E even though the song is in F#.

This is part of Morello’s style and is a popular way to write riffs in general, but not all solid riffs start on the tonic or the one. “Whole Lotta Love” and “Heartbreaker” by Led Zeppelin are examples of classic riffs that don’t start on the one.

Comment: Yes both "Whole Lotta Love" and "Heartbreaker" start with pickup notes, but then land on root on 1.